# What is the proper way to to activate an account via $_GET?

Tags: php, mysql, hash, passwords, get

So right now when a user registers, their password is hashed and stored, their id is stored as a primary key and the cell in the field email_activation is enumerated to 'no' by default.  They are then sent an email where their account can be activated by clicking on the below link.

http://website.com/activation.php?id=1&pass=23a000e03e9116c958dh923542

After clicking on the link the following script runs

```
$id= $_GET['id'];
$hashPass= $_GET['pass'];

mysql_query("UPDATE members SET email_activation='yes' WHERE members_id='$id' AND members_password='$hashPass'")
```

Does this seem like a safe way to activate someone's account considering their hashed pass is part of the URL (assuming proper sanitation of strings, etc...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to put the password, hashed or not, in the link (and no, you shouldn't do that).

Store a *different* random value **in addition to** the password in your database, and then put that random value in the link. (See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce)

Since the random activation value will only be used once (and isn't something that can grant normal access to the account), it's fine to put it in a URL.

Comment: Thanks Amber, I like the idea of basing the activation on a random value that is assigned upon signing up for an account.

Comment: Actually, can you recommend a function in php that generates a random alpha-numeric string of random length?

Comment: You can just write one yourself based off of `rand()` or `mt_rand()`.

Answer (score 3):

No. Use a separate field to contain the activation hash, and base the hash on multiple things (username, password hash, time of day, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, will do.  So in general it's okay to include the activation hash in the URL?

Comment: It's okay as long as the activation code isn't something that can be used more than once to gain access to the account. (The best systems don't even give you access directly; they still require you to log in after activation.)

Answer (score 0):

It's not very safe to do that, no. It would be better to assign a unique and random key instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create another field in your table just for activation.  That way you won't have the password hash in the URL.

(I wasn't quick enough on my response.)